# Is there a way to run nodejs executables created with nexe using pm2?

Tags: node.js, pm2, nexe

I've created an nodejs executable on linux using nexe. I've set my module_conf.json file to the below configurations -

```
{
  "apps" : [{
    "name"       : "nodeapp",
    "script"     : "./app",
    "exec_interpreter": "none",
    "exec_mode"  : "fork_mode"
  }]
}
```

I use `pm2 start ./app` but it doesn't work.
When I see pm2 logs, I get the following error -

```
 TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received undefined
 at validateString (internal/validators.js:120:11)
 at Object.resolve (path.js:980:7)
 at resolveMainPath (internal/modules/run_main.js:12:40)
 at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:65:24)
 at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
 code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}
```